# JFXtras - How to add Change Listener to CalendarTextField?

Tags: javafx, jfxtras

how can I listen to a change in the CalendarTextField in JFXtras? For example a new choosen date from the picker-menu or a typed-in date?

```
    date.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0) {
            System.out.println("EVENT");

        }
    });
```

gives me every movement of the mouse within the field. I didn't find another eventType that makes sense.

I also thought about adding this event filter in the window and check the selected date at every click in the window. But that can't be the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, found it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jfxtras-users/_di6no6QnAI):

```
    date.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> observableValue,
                Calendar oldValue, Calendar newValue) {
            System.out.println(oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
        }
    });
```

I didn't realize that in FX a listener has to be set to the property, not to the component like in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I have redesigned a calendar component in a `control` with FXML, for the picker-menu I use the `XCalendarPicker` and I add a changelistener to it `calendar()` (who is a property). And when a date is changed I update my textfield with the new `Date`

```
final XCalendarPicker calendarPicker = new XCalendarPicker();

final ChangeListener<Calendar> calendarListener = new ChangeListener<Calendar>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Calendar> observable, Calendar oldValue, Calendar newValue) {
                Date date = newValue.getTime();
                setDate(date);
            }
        };

        calendarPicker.calendar().addListener(calendarListener);
```

Comment: Thanks! What was your reason for not using the CalendarTextField in JFXtras? I'm sure there's a way to add a listener to it.

Comment: The only reason, it I don't want user can type there own date, they can only choose from the picker. but I'm sure if I add a listener to my textfield it can be edited with no problems, you just need to check if the entered date match with your dateformat.